# pass a number into an array using a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have to do a function to return an array with all positive numbers from 0 to n (inclusive, meaning `n` should be included in the array and `n` will be a number passed to the function as parameter.

This is what i have:

```
function arrayWithNumbersUpTo(n) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
        return arr;
    }
}
var arr = [];
```

I've been struggling for over two hours to do what I am sure is a simple solution, please help!

Comment: Walk through your code with a debugger, and you will find out what is happening soon enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `return` **outside** the `for` loop:

```
function arrayWithNumbersUpTo(n){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Haha no problem :) We've all been there!